# Converting a stroke to an object in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, stroke

I wan't to convert a stroke to an object in InDesign. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Copy into Illustrator, expand, copy back to inDesign?

Comment: Unfortunately, you just can't... As suggested above, you should use Illustrator. Copy object, paste it in a new Illustrator doc. Object > Paths > Outline strokes. Copy, and paste it in INDD. If the object is complex, you'd better place it than pasting it.

Comment: @joojaa please avoid answering questions in the comments. Dont'be afraid to post a short answer if you are confident it's the right one.

Comment: @Vincent im trying to deduce is using illustrator is an option. As im not sure if its possible or not in indesign. But you can paste it to illustrator.

Comment: You probably can't. InDesign is primarily a pagination/layout tool so it has limited vector features compared to AI. Process your artwork outside ID, then link to finished AI and/or PSD files in ID.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently you can not. You have to do it outside inDesign. One way is to copy the thing you want to expand into Illustrator, expand there and copy back to inDesign.

Answer (score 0):

Create a picture box. Copy and paste in place so a new box sits over the original picture box. Then resize the box smaller to create the impression of a stroke to whatever thickness you want. Then select both boxes, go to Pathfinder, hit Subtract and you can then paste anything into this "frame". Hope that helps...